# Number of Dyck paths with k returns and b peaks

Tags: co.combinatorics, catalan-numbers

The number of Dyck paths from the origin to $(2n,0)$ which touch the $x$-axis $k+2$ times ($k$ internal touches) is given by
$$\frac{k}{2n-k}{2n-k \choose n}.$$

The number of Dyck paths from the origin to $(2n,0)$ which have $b$ peaks (i.e. local maxima) is given by the Narayana numbers
$$\frac{1}{n}{n \choose b}{n \choose b-1}.$$

My questions is: What is the number of Dyck paths from the origin to $(2n,0)$ which have both $k$ returns and $b$ peaks?

I have not been able to find any published work on this.

Thanks!

Comment: doubly posted MSE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042481/number-of-dyck-paths-with-k-returns-and-b-peaks

Comment: The generating function is quite easy to obtain from the first-passage decomposition:  $-2pq/(q\sqrt{(1-p)^2t^2-2(1+p)t+1}-(1-p)qt-q+2)$.  It should not be hard to simplify and derive the coefficients from that.

Comment: Thank you, Martin Rubey!  I am not familiar with first-passage decompositions.  I will look it up.  Will you briefly explain the basic outline/setup for this particular problem?  Thanks again!

Comment: See Emeric Deutsch, Dyck Path Enumeration, Discrete Mathematics 204 (1999) 167-202, section 6.5, http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X98003719

Answer (score -1):

> What is the number of Dyck Paths from the origin to (2n,0) which have both k returns and b peaks?

For each set of Dyck paths with a semilength of $n$ there is a different triangle array relating returns and peaks.

Let $F(n,b,k)$ be the number of Dyck paths of semilength $n$ that have $b$ peaks (rows in the tables below) and $k$ internal returns to the x axis (columns).

```
n=4
b\k    0   1   2   3
1:     1
2:     3   3
3:     1   2   3
4:     0   0   0   1
```

$F(4,2,1)=3$, so there are 3 Dyck paths of semilength 4 with 2 peaks and 1 internal return to the x axis (`uudduudd`, `uduuuddd`, `uuudddud`)

```
n=7
b\k  0    1     2    3    4    5    6
1:   1
2:  15    6
3:  50   40    15
4:  50   60    45   20
5:  15   24    27   24   15
6:   1    2     3    4    5    6
7:   0    0     0    0    0    0    1
```

$F(7,4,2)=45$, so there are 45 Dyck paths of semilength 7 with 4 peaks and 2 internal returns to the x axis.

The formula deriving the triangular solution arrays involves multiplying 3 arrays.  Also the formula yields a solution array for $k+1$ returns.  (The return at the end of the Dyck path is counted.) So, the indexing at top of the array must be reduced by 1 for the solution requested.  This was done for the two arrays ($n=4$) and ($n=7$) above.

$F(n,b,r)=M(n,b)\times I(n,b,r)\times D(b,r)$, with $r=k+1$ returns, where:

$\displaystyle M(n,b) = \frac{(n-b+1)!}{b!(b-1)!n!}$

```
M(n,b):
b
1:   1
2:   (n-1)/(1!x 2!)
3:  [(n-1)(n-2)]/(2!x 3!)
4:  [(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)]/(3!x 4!)
b:  [(n-1)(n-2)…(n-b+1)]/[(b-1)!x b!]
```

$\displaystyle I(n,b,r) = \frac{(n-b)!}{(n-r)!}$

```
I(n,b,r):
b\r  1                  2                   3                       4      
         …     b
1:   1          
2:   (n-2)              1
3:   (n-2)(n-3)         (n-3)               1
4:   (n-2)(n-3)(n-4)    (n-3)(n-4)          (n-4)                   1
b:   (n-2)(n-3)…(n-b)   (n-3)(n-4)…(n-b)    (n-4)(n-5)…(n-b)        (n-5)…(n-b)     …     1
```

$D(b,1)=1$ and recursively $D(b,r)=r\times D(b-1,r-1)+D(b-1,r)$.

```
D(b,r):
b\r   1    2    3    4    5  … r
1:    1
2:    1    2!
3:    1    4    3!  
4:    1    6    18  4!
5:    1    8    36  96  5!
b:    1    D(b,r)=r x D(b-1,r-1)+D(b-1,r)    … b!
```

For determining  the number of Dyck paths of semilength 10 with 5 peaks and 2 internal returns to the x axis, use the arrays to find $F(10,5,3)$.

$$\begin{align}
F(10,5,3)&=M(10,5)\times I(5,3)\times D(5,3)\\
&=\frac{(10-1)(10-2)(10-3)(10-4)}{4!5!} \times (10-4)(10-5) \times 36\\
&=113
\end{align}$$

The sum of the triangle solution arrays makes a lovely numerical tetrahedron. For more information see Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences [A253938](https://oeis.org/A253938).

Comment: This forum support LaTeX :)

Answer (score -1):

I have simplified my equation.

$n=$ length of Dyck path, $r=$ returns to the $x$-axis, $p=$ peaks

$$F(n,p,r)=  \frac{r(n-1)!(n-r-1)!}{p!(p-r)!(n-p)!(n-p-1)!}.$$

If $n=p=r$, then $F(n,p,r)=1$.

Example:

$$F(7,4,3) = \frac{3\times 6!\times 3!}{4!\times 1!\times 3!\times 2!} = 45.$$

There are $45$ Dyck paths with $4$ peaks, $3$ returns and a length of $7$.